# Fourier transform of unbounded linear operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory

I am trying to construct Fourier transform of a family of unbounded linear operators.

Here is the construction.

Fix $H$ a Hilbert space. Let $D\subset H$ be a fixed dense subset.
Denote by $L(H)$ some set of (possibly unbounded) linear operators on $H$ that are densely defined on $D$.

Let $X = \mathbb{R}^n$.

Starting with an operator-valued mapping $X\ni t \mapsto T_t \in L(H)$. Assume that

1. For every $u\in D$ and $v\in H$, the pairing $\langle v, T_t u\rangle_H$ is a *square integrable function of $t$*.
2. There exists an operator-valued mapping $X\ni k \mapsto T'_k \in L(H)$ such that, for every $u\in D$ and $v\in H$, the Fourier transform of the function $t\mapsto \langle v, T_t u\rangle_H$ is the function $k\mapsto \langle  v, T'_k u\rangle_H$.

I wish to call $T'_k$ the Fourier transform of $T_t$.

#### My Questions

1. Is the above construction flawed?
2. Consider the set $A=\{T_{t}|\int_{X}dt |\langle v,T_{t}u\rangle_{H}|^{2}<\infty\: \text{for all}\: u\in D, v\in H.\}$. Can we construct a linear surjection from $A$ to itself through Fourier transform? The motivation is that it ensures Fourier transform is well-defined for every $T_{t}$ in $A$.

Comment: $t$ is a real variable, right? If so, shouldn't $T'$ depend on some real variable as well?

Comment: I still don't understand the question after the edit… What is t, what is k? Of which function do you take the Fourier transform?

Comment: In regards to your first question, when $H$ is finite dimensional, this seems to be an okay definition, so up to maybe some technical measurability issues I don't see obvious problems with your definition. However, I have no idea what is the point of your second question, nor how it relates to the Fourier transform construction.

Comment: Thank you for your edits!

Comment: @WillieWong For the second question, since I want the Fourier transform defined on every operator in $L(H)$, I think if the map is not surjective, there may exists an operator which is square-integrable in the above sense, but its fourier transform fail to be in the form of $<v,T'_{k}u>$.

Comment: For the continuity of the map, I am not sure what topology is suitable on $L(H)$, so I don't specify the topology on it.  I will address that in my question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I also got stuck at "Fourier transform of operator" vs. "of operator valued function".

Comment: I deleted some of my earlier comments, since with the most recent edit the question is now clear.

Comment: For every $u \in D$ and $v\in H$, given $T\in A$ your construction now defines (almost everywhere) a scalar $L^2$ function $X\ni k\mapsto F(k; u,v)$. Your question is then basically whether it is possible to recover the operator $T'_k$ from the quadratic form $F(k;u,v)$. The limited results I know about this usually requires something stricter than  $L(H)$ (using Lax-Milgram type constructions where $D$ is equipped with an inner product stronger than $H$ and requiring the $T_t:D\to H$ to be bounded).

Comment: Note also that if $T$ is such that $\langle v,T_t u\rangle$ is $L^1$, then the function $F(k;u,v)$ should be continuous in $k$ and well-defined everywhere. If you are in the position where you can equip $D$ with a norm such that $T_t: D\to H$ is always bounded, then instead of $A$ you can probably ask for $T: X\in t \mapsto T_t \in L^2(X; B(D,H))$ to belong to a Bochner space, and then I think what you want can probably be done.

Comment: So my question is: does your setup really require that degree of generality that you are putting in your question, or can you require your $T_t$ to be somewhat more regular than you have spcified?

Comment: I guess your setup is suitable for me, thank you.